# Make dropdown menu same width as navbar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive

I've tried all I can think of and looked for my specific situation. The menu is working fine. I just want the drop-down to be the same width as the top. I know it is a matter of the padding, but the drop-down is inside the UL so it keeps those values. I am stumped. If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. Here is my code below. I also created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/newsong80/xmay5rzc/3/#&togetherjs=UMMs4ad5vj).

HTML:

```
 <ul class="livability-menu">
      <li class="livability">County Overview
        <div class="more">more >></div>
      </li><ul class="dropDown">
        <li><a class="livability-a" href="education.html">Education</a></li>
        <li><a class="livability-a" href="healthcare.html">Healthcare</a></li>
        <li><a class="livability-a" href="housing.html">Housing</a></li>
      </ul>
         </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.livability-menu {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}
.more {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
}
ul.dropDown {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
    -moz-transition: all .25s;
    -ms-transition: all .25s;
    -o-transition: all .25s;
    transition: all .25s;
}
ul.livability-menu:hover .dropDown {
    list-style-type: none;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 3em;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}
li.livability {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}
a.livability-a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
a.livability-a:hover {
    color: #EBF907;
}
a.livability-a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #96D2F8;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your html is invalid... You can not set ul inside `ul` without wrap it in `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a padding problem.

Add `* { outline: 1px dashed }` to the top of your fiddle and you will see immediately that your `.livability-menu` class causes the issue. Set its `padding: 0` and adjust elements and other (child) classes in accordance with your needs.

ATTENTION: while your HTML works fine, officially you are not allowed to nest `UL` elements directly (ul>ul>ul). The proper way for nesting `UL` elements is to put each level inside a `LI` elements (ul>li>ul>li>ul).

Comment: That fixed it. How simple! Thank you!

Comment: please put attention to invalid html

Comment: Please be so nice to add a corrected Fiddle to you post, so others can compare and learn from your mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wapettyjohn/8h7ey36p/4/)'s a fork of your JSFiddle that solves the problem.

You just needed to set `padding: 0;` on `ul.livability-menu` and move `padding: 10px 15px;` to `li.livability`.

Edit: I also fixed the improper ul nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding:0` instead `ul.livability-menu {padding: 10px 15px;}`

```css
ul.livability-menu {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}
.more {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
}
ul.dropDown {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
    -moz-transition: all .25s;
    -ms-transition: all .25s;
    -o-transition: all .25s;
    transition: all .25s;
}
ul.livability-menu:hover .dropDown {
    list-style-type: none;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 3em;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}
li.livability {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}
a.livability-a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
a.livability-a:hover {
    color: #EBF907;
}
a.livability-a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #96D2F8;
}
```

```html
<ul class="livability-menu">
      <li class="livability">County Overview
        <div class="more">more >></div>
      </li>
<li>
<ul class="dropDown">
        <li><a class="livability-a" href="education.html">Education</a></li>
        <li><a class="livability-a" href="healthcare.html">Healthcare</a></li>
        <li><a class="livability-a" href="housing.html">Housing</a></li>
</li>
      </ul>
         </ul>
```

Note!
Your html is invalid... You can not set `ul` inside `ul` without wrap it in `li`
so wrap the second `ul` in `li`